# Dropdown menu: Submenu name is below the menu bar and not within the nav box

Tags: css

I've coded a css dropdown menu and cant seem to get the name "LOGOS" to stay within the green box when I hover over the word "Illustration". I've made the word 5em so I can see it. Cant get it to stay in the box...no control of it's position. Can you help?
Thanks,
T.

```
    <div id="nav-bar-sm-cont">

<ul id="sm-nav">


<li id="home"><a href="index.html" target="_self">HOME</a></li>

<li id="about"><a href="profile.html" target="_self">PROFILE</a></li>

<li id="illustration"><a href="illustration.html" target="_self">ILLUSTRATION</a>

<ul>

<li id="logos"><a href="logos.html" target="_self">LOGOS</a></li>

</ul>

</li>


<li id="billboards"><a href="artman-billboards.html" target="_self">BILLBOARDS</a></li>

<li id="six-mo"><a href="art_prize.html" target="_self">6 MO BREAKFAST</a></li>

<li id="cal"><a href="artshow.html" target="_self">ARTSHOW</a></li>

<li id="church"><a href="churchwork.html" target="_self">CHURCH</a></li>

<li id="contact"><a href="mailto:artman@artmangraphicdesign.com">CONTACT</a></li>

<li id="cat-ill"><a href="catillustration.html" target="_self">CAT ILLUSTRATION</a></li>

<li id="contact-cat"><a href="mailto:cat@bciwildblue.com">CONTACT CAT</a></li>



</ul>
</div>


<!--end nav bar sm container -->

        /* START small NAV bar **************************/

#nav-bar-sm-cont { position: absolute;
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;



}

#sm-nav li { position: relative;
top: 30px;
left: 35px;
font-size: .6em;
line-height: 250%; 
letter-spacing: 0.3em;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;

}


#sm-nav a:link{ text-decoration:none; 
color:silver;
background-color:transparent; 
padding: 5px 5px;



}


#sm-nav a:visited {text-decoration:none;
color: #9781B7; 
padding: 5px 5px;
background-color: transparent;
}

#sm-nav a:hover {text-decoration:none; 
color: #fff; 
background-color:#a7d6d5; 
 padding: 5px 5px;

}
#sm-nav a:active {text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
background-color: green;
padding: 5px 5px;

}


/*start drop down************************************/

#sm-nav li ul { position:relative;
list-style-type: none;
display: none;



}

#sm-nav li:hover ul  { position: absolute;
background: green; 
padding: 5px 5px;
display:block;
 font-size: 5em;
width: 103px;
height: 10px;


}


/*end drop down*****************************************/




/* END small NAV BAR *****************************/
```

Comment: Could you add the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your CSS for the `li` is affecting both the parent `li` and the child. To fix that just change:

```
#sm-nav li {
```

to

```
#sm-nav > li {
```

Now that CSS will only affect the parent `li` and you're free to adjust the CSS for the child however you want like this:

```
#sm-nav li:hover ul li { }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnh3285f/)